# ARRAY - null, positive elements' amount and positive elements' summation

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, swap

I tried to write a code but got stuck...

Task is: It is given integers' array C(15).Find null, positive elements' amount and            positive elements' summation. The found meanings put in the middle of the array. Show the initial and changed arrays.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int array1[15]={-1, 0, -3, -2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, -5, -4, 7, 8, 9};
int maxarray=array1[0];
int maxarrayplace;
int minarray=0;


//1
for (int inindex=0; inindex<15; inindex++)
{
    int minindex=inindex;
        for (int preindex=inindex+1; preindex<15; preindex++)
        {
            if (array1[preindex]<array1[minindex])
            minindex=preindex;
        }
        swap(array1[inindex], array1[minindex]);

}

cout<<"Array1 is "<<array1[15];
for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
{
    cout<<array1[i]<<" ";
}

//2



cout<<"\nPositive numbers: \n";

for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
if (array1[i]>minarray)
{
    cout<<array1[i]<<" ";
}

//positive element's amount









 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I misunderstand the goal here... Are you trying to sort the list from smallest to largest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all this line in your code :

```
cout<<"Array1 is "<<array1[15];
```

is incorrect, you can't use the index 15 when the size of your array is 15, last element index is 14.
using index 15 should give you "out of bound" exception.

Also if you want to show the positive numbers, you only need to compare them with zero , and the code below will also show the amount and the sum of the positive numbers :

```
cout<<"\nPositive numbers: \n";
int amount = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
 if (array1[i]>0)
 {
    cout<<array1[i]<<" ";
    amount++;
    sum += array1[i];
 }
cout<<"The amount of the positive numbers is : "<<amount<<"\n";
cout<<"The summation of the positive numbers is : "<<sum<<"\n";
```

If this is not what you're looking for, please explain more clearly.

Comment: Thanks, @T-D! This is what I needed to get for the right answer.